# How to figure out which resource to enter in Google Cloud Policy troubleshooter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-iam

I'd like to give a colleague permission via IAM on a Google Cloud Monitoring resource. He send me the error message

```
Error loading /monitoring/alerting/incidents/[incident id]?project=[project]
```

and the roles that are necessary to proceed from the error message:

```
monitoring.incidents.get
stackdriver.projects.get
```

I assume that I can use Policy troubleshooter in order to list the required role I need to assign in IAM, but maybe that's a misunderstanding.

Assuming that can use the troubleshooter, I entered my colleagues e-mail address which is used for Google Cloud login as well as one pair with `Permission` `monitoring.incidents.get`. I tried the following for `Resource`:

```
/monitoring/alerting/incidents/[incident id]
/monitoring/alerting/incidents/[incident id]?project=[project]
//monitoring/alerting/incidents/[incident id]
//monitoring/alerting/incidents/[incident id]?project=[project]
//monitoring/alerting/incidents
//monitoring.googleapis.com/alerting/incidents/[incident id]
//monitoring.googleapis.com/alerting/incidents/[incident id]?project=[project]
//monitoring.googleapis.com/alerting/incidents
```

The UI doesn't provide any support in filling out this field nor any feedback in the error message. As far as I understand [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names?hl=en) the full form with `monitoring.googleapis.com` is expected.

I don't have logging turned on, so I cannot use the Log explorer as suggested.

Comment: You can't set IAM allow policies on an incident, so by the same rule you can't inspect IAM allow policies on an incident. Monitoring permissions are granted on a project level so you can inspect them on a project level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's [IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) provides a table mapping **permissions** to the **pre-defined roles** that contain them.

This table is searchable, so you should be able to pop in the target permission to find predefined roles that already contain it. Then, you just need to scan through the results looking for a role that makes sense for your use-case. For example:

[image: screenshot showing roles that grant the stackdriver.projects.get permission]

While this generally works pretty well, I'm actually not seeing any results for `monitoring.incidents.get`! This is the first permission I've personally come across that was not included in this table -- this feels like a documentation bug to me. Maybe this is also what was giving you grief in the Policy Troubleshooter.

---

An alternative to the permissions reference page is to check the "Access control with IAM" documentation for the specific product you're working with. This page will typically list the pre-defined roles that apply to the given product (and the scopes to which those permissions apply).

In my experience, most Google Cloud products are pretty good about providing this IAM documentation & generally searching for `<product> IAM GCP` should find the correct page.

For example, the "Access control with IAM" page for Monitoring can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control

*Again* though: I'm not seeing any references to the `monitoring.incidents.get` permission. All I can find (at the time of this writing) is an [Incidents](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control#incident_roles_desc) section that suggests incidents access control is managed with the basic `monitoring.viewer`, `monitoring.editor`, and `monitoring.admin` roles.

These roles have worked for me in the past to grant the `monitoring.incidents.update` permission required to close an incident. If these roles would be too broad for your use-case, you can instead [create a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles).